# how to specify Cortex-A53 in arm-none-eabi-gcc?

Tags: c, linux, arm

I'm trying to compile a HELLOWORLD.c with arm-none-eabi-gcc in minGW, the command is like this:

```
D:\code>arm-none-eabi-gcc hello.c -o hello -shared
```

and it worked, and generates an "hello" which details info is like this:(I put it into Ubuntu and file it):

```
gec@ubuntu:/mnt/hgfs/code$ file hello
hello: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

and then I put it into my target plat-form(Cortex-A53) and run, the result is:

```
[root@GEC6818:~]# ./a
Segmentation fault
```

and then, I notice that I should specify the CPU or architecture in the compile command, so I compile like this:

```
D:\code>arm-none-eabi-gcc hello.c -o a -mcpu=cortex-a53 --specs=nosys.specs
```

but it doesn't work, the run result is this:

```
[root@GEC6818:~]# ./a
Killed
```

so, can any body pls help me out??  thanks from the bottom of my heart

Comment: Have you considered that your program might be flawed?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html

Answer (score 2):

From the command-prompt visible in your post, it seems you are trying to execute your program on a Linux system:

```
[root@GEC6818:~]# ./a
Killed
```

If this is the case, you should not use an `arm-none-eabi-gcc` toolchain, which is targeting a baremetal (non-linux) target platform - see [here](http://arm-none-eabi-gcc) for an explanation of the relationship between a gcc toolchain name and the system it is targeting.
 More specifically, the `--specs=nosys.specs` option is supposed to be used when compiling for a system which is not running a general purpose operating system, i.e. Linux .
You should use one of [arm-linux-gnueabihf](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-7/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gcc-linaro-7.4.1-2019.02-i686-mingw32_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz) or [aarch64-linux-gnu](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-7/aarch64-linux-gnu/gcc-linaro-7.4.1-2019.02-i686-mingw32_aarch64-linux-gnu.tar.xz) instead. 
The first toolchain should be used if you are running a 32 bit ARM Linux, the second one if you are running a 64 bit Linux.

You can determine which version you are running using the `file` command on an executable available in your original ARM system, such as `/bin/sh`.
If `/bin/sh` is an ELF 32-bit executable, use `arm-linux-gnueabihf`. If it is an ELF 64-bit executable, use `aarch64-linux-gnu`.